# How not to increment integer value twice by clicking same button again

Tags: c#, asp.net, increment

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
a++;
label1.Text = a.ToString();
```

I have actually used label as you can see to show the result. But when I click button once more, value increments again. I don't want to disable button also. And want to keep the value that was incremented before.

In short value increments only once when i click a button and stops increment.

I am designing a quiz application.

Comment: Have a class level `bool`, set it to true on first click and check that `bool` before incrementing. This also depends on what kind of application you are targeting, for ASP.Net applications, you have to maintain state for your `bool` check, since it will be lost after first post back.

Comment: Use a bool, set it at first increment, check it at second increment.

Comment: `I don't want to disable button also.` why not? That would be the correct behavior for a button that no longer does anything. Otherwise the user will keep clicking and wonder why nothing happens.

Comment: @MattBurland: Possible Scenario: The button does also something else then incrementing. But it doesn't make any sense then ...

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = int.Parse(label1.Text);

if(a < int.parse(label1.Text) + 1)
   a++;

label1.Text = a.ToString();
```

Comment: Since you are resetting `a` each time, this will always be less than what is basically `a+1`. Presumably you mean that the first line isn't part of the event handler, in which case you should make that clear.

Comment: Why not if (a < a +1) then? But @MattBurland is right anyway ;)